# Elasticsearch Java TermVectorRequest (_termvector)

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

I have executed the following query in my browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/type/id/_termvector
```

Which returns:

```
"_index" : "index",
"_type" : "type",
"_id" : "id",
"_version" : 1,
"found" : true,
"took" : 2,
"term_vectors" : {
  "text" : {
    "field_statistics" : {
      "sum_doc_freq" : 100453,
      "doc_count" : 3566,
      "sum_ttf" : 126632
    },
    "terms" : {
      "trust" : {
        "term_freq" : 1
      },
      "believe" : {
        "term_freq" : 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the Java API counterpart TermVectorRequest/Response, like so:

```
TermVectorResponse tvr = client.prepareTermVector().setIndex(index).setType(type).setId(id).execute().actionGet();
```

I have absolutely no clue how to retrieve and parse the result from the API call or if the function I use is correct.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

I finally managed to parse the response into json.

```
TermVectorResponse resp = client.prepareTermVector().setIndex(index).setType(type).setId(id).execute().actionGet();
XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
builder.startObject();
resp.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
builder.endObject();
System.out.println(builder.string());
```

Don't forget to use the `builder.startObject()` and `builder.endObject()`, otherwise it will not output correct json.

This gives the expected output.

**Bonus:**
To convert the json into a `Map<String,Object>` use

```
Map<String, Object> map = XContentHelper.convertToMap(builder.bytes(), false).v2();
```